# prolog is X the median of numbers A, B, C

Tags: list, prolog, median

I am having a bit of trouble with prolog as I have just started learning it. I am unsure how to test if X is the median of A, B, C. My first thought was to make a list of A, B, C and then sort it. I would then check if X is equal to the second number. The problem being that I don't know how to take three values and turn them into a list (If you can). Is this even the most effecent way to do this? Honestly I have no Idea so any insite would be helpful.

Comment: Simply insert them into a list and then call sort predicate. It is easiest thing in prolog to put things  in lists as it does not do type checking.

Comment: If you want to put `A`, `B`, and `C` into a list, `[A,B,C]` is a list consisting of `A`, `B`, and `C`. You just have to write it.

Comment: Four answers were given. Were none of them acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

this is a very basic solution, with a sorting only accepting 3 values, but it should make the problem solved.

```
  is_median_of_sorted([_, ValueToCheck, _],ValueToCheck).

  sorted_list_of_3([A,B,C],R) :- 
      A>B, A>C, B>C, R = [A,B,C];
      A>C, A>B, C>B, R = [A,C,B];
      B>A, B>C, A>C, R = [B,A,C];
      B>C, B>A, C>A, R = [B,C,A];
      C>A, C>B, A>B, R = [C,A,B];
      C>B, C>A, B>A, R = [C,B,A].

  is_median_of_3(List, ValueToCheck) :-
      sorted_list_of_3(List,SortedList),
      is_median_of_sorted(SortedList, ValueToCheck).
```

To check it, query:

```
    is_median_of_3([1,10,4],4).
```

Or if you want to check what is the median of a given list:

```
    is_median_of_3([1,10,4],X).
```

You can also check it via browser at: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/three_values_median.pl

What is does is : **is_median_of_3** first gets a matching sorted list, and then checks agains **is_median_of_sorted**, which just picks a 2nd element of the list.

Hope I could help.

Comment: What if you had 20 variables? Would you have written 20 times all variables?

Comment: :) Of course not - it is just a trivial example for a given question for median of 3. For sorting like N variables you can implement quick sort or any other example and take a value in the middle. - like in another answer here. My point was to easily show how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a modular program, you had to insert all the elements in a list, sort it and find the median. This could be done in this way:

```
findMedian([H|_],0,H):- !.
findMedian([_|T],C,X):-
    C1 is C-1,
    findMedian(T,C1,X).

median(L,X):-
    msort(L,SortedL),
    length(SortedL,Len),
    Len2 is Len//2,
    findMedian(SortedL,Len2,X).

?- median([1,10,4,5,7],X).
X = 5
?- median([1,10,4,5,7],5).
true
```

This solution will works also with list with an even number of elements, returning the element after the middle of the list (ex. 4 elements, `[0,1,2,3]`, it returns `2`). In this case you have to decide what to do (fail, return the two elements in the middle ecc...)

EDIT: as suggested in the comment, you should use `msort/2` instead `sort/2` because `sort/2` removes duplicated elements.

Comment: Be careful here. `sort` eliminates duplicates. So if you have any repeated elements, which should be a valid case, it will not work properly. You can use `msort/2` instead.

Comment: You are definitely right @lurker, thanks for notice it

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a solution similar to @damianodamiano's, but I would find the middle element of a list without using `length/2`:

```
median(List, Median) :-
    msort(List, SortedList),
    middle_element(SortedList, SortedList, Median).

middle_element([], [M|_], M).
middle_element([_], [M|_], M).
middle_element([_,_|Xs], [_|Ys], M) :-
    middle_element(Xs, Ys, M).
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to "*check if X is the median of A,B,C?*" is:

```
is_median_of_3(A,B,C,X):-
    msort([A,B,C],[_,X,_]).
```

This will try to match if `[A,B,C]` sorted consists of any list (of three elements) with `X` as the middle element.

---

I don't know everywhere, but in [swish](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) there are residuals coming out from `msort` as such:

```
msort([2,8,4],L).



L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = []

L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = [_1080]

L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = [_1122, _1128]

L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = [_1170, _1176, _1182]

L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = [_1224, _1230, _1236, _1242]

L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = [_1284, _1290, _1296, _1302, _1308]

L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = [_716, _722, _728, _734, _740, _746]

L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = [_788, _794, _800, _806, _812, _818, _824]

L = [2, 4, 8],
_residuals = [_866, _872, _878, _884, _890, _896, _902, _908]
```

and so on...

Also, I couldn't test it in [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_prolog_online.php) because it seems broken.

Comment: What do you mean with "there are residuals coming out from `msort/2`"? Can you post an example?

Comment: @damianodamiano see my update for example with `msort/2` in swish

Comment: Are you writing `msort([2,8,4],L)` directly in the query on in a program? Because in both cases, i don't get `_residuals` but only the list sorted... @Rafalon

Comment: @damianodamiano Directly in the query, but maybe it's only on my computer or browser. Anyway `_residuals` isn't expected here so if I'm the only one seeing this, then my answer is valid :)

Comment: Haha, I just checked on FF and no `_residuals` ! Then it's most likely IE which is out (should I say as usual ?)

Answer (score 0):

Following a *generate & test* approach you can write:

```
median(List,Median) :-
    dif(List,[]), msort(List,SList), length(List,Len),
    append(Low,[Median],Tmp), append(Tmp,High,SList),
    length(Low,LowLen), div(Len,2)=:=LowLen, !.
```

This has a convenient declarative reading: `Median` is the value of a non-empty `List` that splits the sorted version `SList` of `List` into two halves `Low` and `High`, viz. `Median` is the "middle element" of the distribution of the values in `List`.

Indeed, the program above determines `Median` by checking whether `SList` can be written as a list concatenation `Low + [Median] + High` such that the length of `Low` is half the length of `SList`.  Since `High` is never used (i.e. it is a singleton), the program can be rewritten by substituting it with `_` as in:

```
median(List,Median) :-
    dif(List,[]), msort(List,SList), length(List,Len),
    append(Low,[Median],Tmp), append(Tmp,_,SList),
    length(Low,LowLen), div(Len,2)=:=LowLen, !.
```

Naturally, it is also possible to distinguish the case in which the length of the list is odd from the case it is even, so to return the average of the two median elements in the latter case:

```
median(List,Median) :-
    is_list(List), dif(List,[]), 
    msort(List,SList), length(List,Len),
    median(SList,Len,Median).
    
median(SList,Len,Median) :-
    Len mod 2 =:= 1, 
    append3(Low,[Median],_,SList),
    length(Low,LowLen), div(Len,2)=:=LowLen, !.
median(SList,Len,Median) :-
    Len mod 2 =:= 0, 
    append3(Low,[M1,M2],_,SList),
    length(Low,LowLen), div(Len,2)=:=LowLen + 1,
    Median is (M1+M2)/2, !.

append3(L1,L2,L3,L) :- append(L1,L2,T), append(T,L3,L).
```